# Backspace and Arrow Not Working on VS Code's Bash Terminal in window10

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash, oh-my-zsh

I have followed https://gist.github.com/fworks/af4c896c9de47d827d4caa6fd7154b6b to install **zsh** for **git bash** in **window10**, then I installed On My Zsh and **auto-suggestions** plugins, But after that, the backspace and arrow don't work in the bash terminal(which have `exec zsh`) of VS Code,

But the backspace and arrow key work perfectly fine on **Git Bash(which have `exec zsh`)**

After Debug, I'm sure that error was caused by **auto-suggestions** plugins

Also the **$TERM** in **vscode bash** is xterm-256, and **$TERM** in **Git Bash** is xterm

So, what should I do?